# calculate distance between two locations using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an app using MIT App Inventor.  From the app, I send current location latitude and longitude to php. I have a mysql table which stores the complete address including lat and long. Here is the query.

```
$sSQL= "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$lat1."*pi()/180)) * sin((latitude*pi()/180))+cos((".$lat1."*pi()/180)) * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$long1."- longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance_var FROM  DIVE_LOC HAVING distance_loc < 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";
```

I use the following code in php to compare the distance..

```
$theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

$distance = ($miles * 1.609344);
```

The results are compared , here is the output

```
PHP value - 0.32493112554566 # mySQL value -0.320931017946721
PHP value - 0.49010759578908 # mySQL value -0.49327293708344117
PHP value - 0.49010759578908 # mySQL value -0.49327293708344117
PHP value - 0.65728970497002 # mySQL value -0.6598218485814622
PHP value - 0.88521338025908 # mySQL value -0.8844764825185991
PHP value - 1.1443186694143 # mySQL value -1.1438416915550529.
```

I just want to know if some difference in the values would exist. both cannot be accurately same.

Comment: how about this.  https://geophp.net/

Comment: It may be caused by float or double data type used for calculation in php and used another in mysql.

Comment: It's really weird to convert your units first to miles and then to kms. Why not use km throughout?